# A basic question regarding semidirect product of finite groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I have a basic question regarding the semidirect product $C_m\rtimes C_k$ of two finite cyclic groups.

Does the semidirect product $C_m\rtimes C_k$ represents **a specific** group or rather **a family** of groups satisfying special relations? To sharpen my question, is it true that when we say

"Let be $G$ the group $C_m\rtimes C_k$..."

we refer to a specific group ? My confusion stems from the fact that by

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

the $C_m\rtimes C_k$ is define by the presentation
$$
C_m\rtimes C_k=\langle a, b\mid a^m=1, b^k=1, b^{-1}ab=a^e\rangle,
$$
which, to my understanding, defines a specific group.

Sorry for such basic question but I'm totally confused.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: That's a *presentation*, not a representation.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun, I edit it.

Comment: The semidirect product $G\rtimes_{\phi} H$ depends also on the homomorphism $\phi$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). The case $\phi(h)(n)=hnh^{-1}$ is only one possibility.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. So whenever we say "Let. $G=C_m\rtimes C_k$ we must mention $\phi$ ?

Comment: Yes. If $\phi$ is conjugation then it is as you said also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232747/the-operation-rule-of-the-semidirect-product-c-m-rtimes-c-k?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any two groups $N$ and $H$, the family of groups $N\rtimes H$ (not to confuse with isomorphism classes) is in bijection with the set ${\rm Hom}(H,{\rm Aut}(N))$. The description of $C_m\rtimes C_n$ in the wikipedia article is utilising the fact ${\rm Aut}(C_n)$ is in bijection with the set of numbers in ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$, co-prime to $n$.